Application not a procedure when calling higher order function
I am writing a program that will playback a list of frames as a movie. But before it play it back I want to apply a modifier procedure to every frame in the list. for some reason when calling the update-movie procedure it will say that my draw-cage procedure is not a procedure. even though it very clearly is. I suppose I am doing something wrong within the update-movie procedure?
#lang racket

(require 2htdp/image)
(require 2htdp/universe)


(define bird-imgs (list ...)) ; --> these are all images in the list, nothing else
(define rate 5)
(define (draw-cage img)
  (define cage-frame (rectangle 460 400 "outline" (pen "black" 10 "solid" "round" "round")))
  (overlay/align "middle" "middle"  cage-frame img))
  

(define (update-movie proc frameslst)
  (if (null? frameslst)
      '()
      (update-movie (proc (car frameslst)) (cdr frameslst))))


(run-movie (/ 1 rate) (update-movie draw-cage bird-imgs))

the error is as proceeds:
 application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: (object:image% ... ...)

I've tried enetering the draw-cage procedure as a lambda procedure directly into the call, but got the same error

(draw-cage (car frameslst)) is an image, and on the firt recursion you're passing that as the second argument to update-movie, which expects it to be a procedure.
I suspect that you meant to do
(define (update-movie proc frameslst)
  (if (null? frameslst)
      '()
       (begin
           (proc (car frameslst))
           (update-movie proc (cdr frameslst)))))

